# Using toastr and jquery-ui date picker with Aurelia

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, aurelia

I've got an Aurelia project based on the jspm skeleton.  I'm using both toastr and this datepicker custom attribute https://www.danyow.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-aurelia/.

Each works individually.  However, when I include both in my project I get the following error:

> datePicker.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Any ideas on how to get these to work together?

Comment: If you are using Jspm, that usually happens when two libraries have same dependency but are using different dependency source (i.e. one `jquery` from GitHub and another from npm). Make sure you are importing only one `jquery` in your app.

Comment: In my package.json file I have:  
...
          "jquery": "npm:jquery@^3.0.0",
         "jquery-ui": "github:components/jqueryui@^1.12.1",
          "moment": "npm:moment@^2.13.0",
          "numeral": "npm:numeral@^1.5.3",
          "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.3",
          "toastr": "github:CodeSeven/toastr@^2.1.3"
...

Comment: Check in `config.js` file. It's possible that `github:components/jqueryui` is having a dependency on `github:jquery` or something like that. Take a look at network tab in browser dev tools to confirm whether your browser loads multiple copies of `jquery`.

Comment: Yes, your right I've got conflicting dependencies in config.js
`
 "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "github:components/jqueryui@1.12.1",
  ...
  "toastr": "github:CodeSeven/toastr@2.1.3",
    "github:CodeSeven/toastr@2.1.3": {
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.32",
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@3.1.1"
    },
    "github:components/jqueryui@1.12.1": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.1.1"
    },
 ...
    "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.7": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.1.1"
    },
`

Comment: Thanks!  I manually changed the jquery references in config.js to github:components/jquery@3.1.1 and this resolved the problem.  I'll need to figure out how to prevent those references from being reintroduced the next time I do jspm update.

Comment: np. When you figure it out, let me know :) I always correct the references manually after the update. That's the biggest pain point I have with Jspm. No such problems with Aurelia CLI for now.

Answer (score 0):

As Miroslav indicated above, the error resulted from conflicting jquery dependencies in my config.js file.  Some references were to npm and some were to github.  In my case, I changed all to reference github.
I changed references from:

> "jquery": "npm:jquery@3.1.1"

to

> "jquery": >"github:components/jquery@3.1.1"